# How can I Calculate BAL in NetLogo?

Tags: r, netlogo

I am a beginner in Netlogo, my problem is as following Firstly I have some plants(1000 turtles), these plants have two variables diameter at breast height and height. I want to use the following equation to estimate the competition (See the link):
The formula quantifies the sum of the basal areas of all trees that are larger or equal in basal area compared to that of a given tree (i) at time (t). It is the complement value of the basal area percentile tree (i) denoting relative dominance, where (G(t)) is basal area per hectare of a given forest stand at time (t). Basal area of an individual tree is the cross-sectional area of its stem usually measured at 1.3 m above ground level. For convenience basal area is often calculated from stem diameter using the area formula of a circle. Basal area per hectare is a density measure taking both number of trees and their sizes in a certain area into account. Calculating this equation: first step is the diameter at breast height should be ranked from smallest to maximum  , then basal area for each plant should be calculated and sum of basal area of all trees larger than reference tree(the smallest) are calculated, for the following tree sum of basal area of all trees larger than the two previous smallest trees  ) are calculated, and so on..
the last step : the smallest tree has the largest value and the largest diameter has (0). I tried to write BAL formula in this way, but it did not work, I just got the same result for all turtles, the results should be cumulative even if the dbh is the same ,how to make the function work for all turtles? i.e, the function should exclude the first turtles, then the first two turtles , then the fisrt three turtles , then the first 4 turtles and so on :

```
to calc-treeba                           
   set ba  (pi * (dbh / 2) ^ 2 )      ; ba : tree basal area , pi :3.14, dbh = diameter at breast height
    end

to calc-bal-for-all-trees        ; BAL as non-spatially explicit index
   set  bal sum ([ba] of turtles with [ba > [ba] of myself])
   end
```

Below you can find how BAL is calculated in R but unfortunately that did not help me to apply it in Netlogo.

R code for calculating basal area in larger trees. It is best to define a function in R that you can use at multiple instances in your R script. Such a function could look like the code given in the box below (See the link):

https://blogg.slu.se/forest-biometrics/2017/05/26/basal-area-in-larger-trees-and-the-growth-compensation-point/#comment-1278

Comment: Please use the editing tools to properly format code in your post; it's a bit of a mess at the moment. Also check your mathematical equation(s), I'm struggling to make sense of them the way they're typeset.

Comment: I'm not a NetLogo user so cannot tell what syntactic or semantic errors might exist. You say "it did not work". That tells us very little. Error message appeared? Then post it in full. Erroneous calculations? How can you tell? Do you have the right answer avaialble?  What sort of "work" didn't happen? Are you trying to get halp with translating that function into a formal computer language? Maybe it you asked for help running it just in R you could get more attention. I suspect there are not many NetLogo users reading this and they might see this as an attempt to get homework solution.

Comment: user 42 :  you are right I should to explain more what I got it exactly , I added some explanations , the function works well for R, that is why I mentioned here maybe it helps to shed light where I went wrong .. thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

Did you perhaps set BAL as a global variable instead of a `turtles-own` variable? I have no problem with your code, **assuming** that `calc-bal-for-all-trees` is called by the turtles rather than the observer. For example, with this setup:

```
turtles-own [ ba bal ]

to setup
  ca
  crt 10 [
    set ba 10 + random 50
    set shape "tree"
    set color green
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set size ba / 10    
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

You can run your code like so:

```
to get-bal
  ask turtles [
    set bal sum [ba] of turtles with [ ba > [ba] of myself ]
  ]
end
```

When I check it with something like:

```
to check-bal
  foreach sort-on [ba] turtles [
    current-turtle ->
    ask current-turtle [
      show ( word "BA: " ba ", BAL: " bal )
    ]
  ]
end
```

I get output something like:

```
(turtle 4): "BA: 18, BAL: 301"
(turtle 5): "BA: 21, BAL: 280"
(turtle 3): "BA: 23, BAL: 257"
(turtle 8): "BA: 27, BAL: 230"
(turtle 1): "BA: 29, BAL: 201"
(turtle 0): "BA: 30, BAL: 171"
(turtle 6): "BA: 35, BAL: 136"
(turtle 2): "BA: 37, BAL: 99"
(turtle 7): "BA: 49, BAL: 50"
(turtle 9): "BA: 50, BAL: 0"
```

Is that along the lines of what you're expecting?

Comment: Thank you for good explanation , it helped me a lot to find where I went wrong , I always got bal 0 for all turtles because I initialized one diameter value for all values (0.01). But when I use random numbers, the function works well.but for my case I deal with even-aged forest that is why I should have to suppose the same value for diameter at age (0), so random-normal is good to handel with this problem?

Comment: @OmranYaseen - It might be, but I don't know if I can answer that question- I think it might depend on your model / what initial conditions you expect. My opinion would be that as far as the model goes, introducing some with random-normal makes sense to eliminate duplicate BA values.